# how to track users by session in the Application, i.e. each user has their own set of redirects (rules)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm making a URL shortener( analog bitly).there is a single page. It has a form in which you can enter the URL that should be shortened.
and a sign with all abbreviated URLs (with pagination) of this user.

I use nodejs express, page -react.these are stored in mongodb.

how i can to track users by session in the Application, i.e. each user has their own set of redirects (rules)? WITHOUT authorization.what can be used?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a unique short URL, we can compute it using the Unique Hash(MD5, SHA256, etc.) of the original URL and then encode using base62. If we use the MD5 algorithm as our hash function, it’ll produce a 128-bit hash value. After base62 encoding, we’ll get a string having more than seven characters. We can take the first 7 characters for the key.

reference:
[Designing URL Shortening Service like TinyURL](https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/design-a-url-shortening-service-like-tiny-url)